# web-administration vs WMI to query web directory properties performance problems

Tags: performance, powershell, iis, wmi, iis-metabase

I have been building a server diff script for IIS and i've found that using the web-administration module is dramatically slower than WMI to get the same information. I built the WMI module first as i am working on a 2003 sunset project yet i found when i started into the IIS7 methods it was extremely slow.

Processing time --  IIS7: 348.988, IIS6: 10.309 (seconds)

The biggest time loss is in retrieving the properties for each directory under the webapp, this is taking ~5 seconds per 10 directories or 2 seconds each! WMI can do the entire website in 10 seconds.

```
. C:\scripts\PS\bits\Get-SelectPropertyArray.ps1
# a helper file that converts a field, alias and expression into a selectable property
. C:\scripts\PS\bits\Get-FlagAsList.ps1
# a helper function to tag a series of boolean properties and convert them into a single csv string with the "name" of the flags turned on

function Get-IIS7ConfigForPSPath
{
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string]$PSPath
)


$propsToSelect = @("Name","Path","PSPath")

                    <# Check the FlagValue datatype because when not configured it returns an object instead of an empty string! #>
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Handlers_AccessFlags" {
                        $flagValue = (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/handlers -Name AccessPolicy -PSPath $PSPath)
                        if ($flagValue.GetType().Name -eq "ConfigurationAttribute")
                        { "" } else {$flagValue}
                   }

                   <# Check the FlagValue datatype because when not configured it returns an object instead of an empty string! #>
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Access_sslFlags" {
                       $flagValue =  (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/access -Name sslFlags -PSPath $PSPath)
                       if ($flagValue.GetType().Name -eq "ConfigurationAttribute")
                       { "" } else {$flagValue}
                   }

$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Asp_AppAllowClientDebug" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/asp -Name AppAllowClientDebug -PSPath $PSPath).Value }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Asp_AppAllowDebugging" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/asp -Name AppAllowDebugging -PSPath $PSPath).Value }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Asp_limits_bufferingLimit" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/asp/limits -Name bufferingLimit -PSPath $PSPath).Value }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Asp_EnableParentPaths " {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/asp -Name EnableParentPaths -PSPath $PSPath).Value }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Asp_limits_queueTimeout" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/asp/limits -Name queueTimeout -PSPath $PSPath).Value }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Asp_limits_requestQueueMax" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/asp/limits -Name requestQueueMax -PSPath $PSPath).Value }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "Asp_limits_scriptTimeout" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/asp/limits -Name scriptTimeout -PSPath $PSPath).Value }


$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "security_auth_Anonymous" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication -Name Enabled -PSPath $PSPath).Value }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "security_auth_Basic" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/basicAuthentication -name enabled  -PSPath $PSPath).Value }

$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "web_limits_ConnectionTimeout" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.applicationHost/webLimits -Name ConnectionTimeout -PSPath $PSPath).Value }

$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "HttpCompression_DoDynamicCompression" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/httpCompression/scheme -Name DoDynamicCompression -PSPath $PSPath).Value }
$propsToSelect += Get-SelectPropertyArraySet "." "HttpCompression_DoStaticCompression" {
                    (get-webconfigurationProperty -filter /system.webServer/httpCompression/scheme -Name DoStaticCompression -PSPath $PSPath).Value  }

# convert property array sets into selectable properties
$props = $propsToSelect | Get-SelectPropertyArray2

# retrieve the properties, no pipeline input is required as we are doing all the logic in the script blocks

$config = Get-Item $PSPath | select -Property $props
if ( !($config.Path) -or $config.Path -eq $null)
{
    $config.Path = $PSPath
}
return $config
}

Get-IIS7ConfigForPSPath -PSPath ("IIS:Sites\{0}" -f $iis7Site.name)
```

This is the one that is killing me as i have to do this 160+ times per virtual directory:

```
 Get-IIS7ConfigForPSPath -PSPath $iis7vwebfolderpath
```

by comparison here is my WMI request:

```
$start = [System.DateTime]::Now
$numanalyzed = 0
$iis6VWebDirConfig = @()
foreach ($vdir in $iis6VirDirConfig)
{



    #retrieve the desired fields for the web directory
    $iis6VWebDirConfig += Get-WmiObject -class IIsWebDirectorySetting -Namespace "root/MicrosoftIISv2" `
                            -Filter ("Name like '"+$vdir.Name+"%'") |
                                select -Property $props

    $numAnalyzed++
    $end = [System.DateTime]::Now
    $timeSoFar = (NEW-TIMESPAN -Start $Start -End $End).TotalSeconds
    $timeremaining = ($iis6VirDirConfig.Count - $numAnalyzed) * ($timeSoFar / $numanalyzed)
    "Analyzed {0} so far... took {1} seconds, remaining time {2} seconds" -f $numanalyzed,$timeSoFar,$timeremaining  | write-host
    "Current Folder: {0}" -f $folder.FullName | Write-Host
}

"Web Directories Found: {0}" -f $iis6VWebDirConfig.Count | Write-Host
$end = [System.DateTime]::Now
"Processed web dirs: {0} took {1} seconds" -f $iis7VWebDirConfig.Count,(NEW-TIMESPAN -Start $Start -End $End).TotalSeconds | write-host   | Write-Host
```

anyone know of a better way to get all those properties from IIS7 metabase? i'm concerned about forward support of WMI in the long run and i've found 1 or 2 properties that are incorrect when retrieved by WMI.

Comment: Why are you concerned about forward support of WMI?

Comment: in case there is ever a change here and i figure using the IIS metabase is the right way to go long term. i also found WMI to be inaccurate for one of the timeout properties.